How to set search paths for Heroku PostgreSQL database?
I'm currently deploying a Django app to Heroku, and my settings.py looks like this:
if IS_HEROKU_APP:
    DATABASE_URL = dj_database_url.config(
        env="DATABASE_URL",
        conn_max_age=600,
        conn_health_checks=True,
        ssl_require=True,
    )
else:
    DATABASE_URL = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        **DATABASE_URL,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public'
        },
    },
    'modules': {
        **DATABASE_URL,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=modules'
        },
    },
    'alumni': {
        **DATABASE_URL,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=alumni'
        },
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['MCMT.db_routers.ModulesRouter', 'MCMT.db_routers.AlumniRouter', 'MCMT.db_routers.DefaultRouter']

This works locally but not when I push to Heroku (specifically in the release phase, when I have to migrate). I get the error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "info" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: SELECT "info"."code" FROM "info"

which is because there is no table "info", only "modules.info". I think this is because Heroku failed to see the search_path options. How should I resolve this?
I have tried to create the schemas first using heroku pg:psql, but that gives me the same error. I also tried to see if it's an issue with dj_database_url but I fail to find any solution online.
